# Inserting items into mongoDB ver 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, web-scraping, scrapy

While finishing my scrapy spider, I was trying out mongoDB as a way to get my items into a database. This was done with mongoDB 4.0 and my private database (Localhost with port 27017).

Now I need to get the items into a real database and thats where Im at.

I got a mongoDB running (3.4 version with username, password, server, etc) but I cant seem to be able to find how to connect to it.

With mongoDB 4.0 I have this (In scrapy pipelines)

```
import pymongo

from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log


class ScrapytestPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)

        db = self.conn['Products1']
        self.collection = db['Computers']



    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))

        return item
```

And that works perfectly.

Any idea on how to connect to a 3.4 mongoDB? And do i need to change the code for it to work in the older version?.

Comment: Are you trying to write to mongodb atlas?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the late response

Comment: See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/ for how to connect to an Atlas instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is replace `self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)` with `self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient('your_connection_string')`.

To get your connection string:

1. Login to your Atlas cluster.
2. Hit the connect button, then select connect with your application.
3. Copy the connection string and update the password.